# How to normalize nested json using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize, nested-json

I want to normalize the "values" array

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "page_call",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "about": 11,
            "videos": 2,
            "posts": 15,
            "home": 21
          },
          "end_time": "2020-11-02T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": null,
      "description": "Number of people who logged in.",
      "id": "1545/lifetime"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried `df_results = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['data'])` , the columns I'm getting are `['name', 'period', 'values', 'title', 'description', 'id']` but the "values" is not getting normalized, can anyone help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df_results = pd.json_normalize(data['data'], 'values', ['name','period','title','description','id'])
print (df_results)
                   end_time  value.about  value.videos  value.posts  \
0  2020-11-02T08:00:00+0000           11             2           15   

   value.home       name    period title                      description  \
0          21  page_call  lifetime  null  Number of people who logged in.   

              id  
0  1545/lifetime
```

Comment: thank you jezrael for your solution, can you please tell me is there any way to just normalize till "values" not "values -> value", because it's giving lots of unnecessary columns

Comment: @kunal - what is `print (df_results.columns)` ?

Comment: @kunal - it is possible, but be careful for duplciated columns names `df_results.columns = df_results.columns.str.removeprefix("value.")`

Comment: no, I'm talking about the "values" key only (data -> values)

Comment: @kunal - Unfortunately not understand

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df_results = pd.json_normalize(data, ["data"])
vals = pd.json_normalize(data, ["data", 'values'])
res = pd.concat([df_results, vals], axis = 1)
del res['values']
res
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it's not working

Comment: What is the problem? As you can see I have tested it with your sample data.

Comment: ['name', 'period', 'values', 'title', 'description', 'id'], this is I'm getting

Comment: The result is in res not df_results.